# In-page link works in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: urls, links, google-chrome

This is a follow-up to:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48521592/1697709

The standard way of using

```
http://example.com/page#design
```

as link into

```
<h2 id="design">Design</h2>
```

does not make the browser to jump this header to the top of the page.

```
<a name="design"><h2>Design</h2></a>
```

does it on Firefox, following

https://www.kasareviews.com/wordpress-page-jump-links/

It also works in Internet Explorer.

But it does not work on Google Chrome. What else should I do to make it work on Chrome?

Comment: Both `<a name="design"><h2>Design</h2></a>` and `<h2 id="design">Design</h2>` work just fine as jump targets when linking to `#design` in my chromium. Is it OS specific, or chrome version specific? Do you have any JavaScripts interfering?

Comment: Works fine for me too. Suggest you try the usual troubleshooting techniques - clear cache, delete preferences, create new user account on your 'puter and try it there, etc.